# read the pdf and display in IE,

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, pdf

I want to read and display the PDF stored in localdrive using java and angularjs and should work in IE and chrome.

Below code works in Chrome but not in IE.

html

```
<div class="tab-content" ng-controller="pdfViewController" style="max-height: 600px; overflow:hidden">
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"  style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div> 
</div>

js code:
app.controller('pdfViewController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $sce, MyPDFService, $window) {
    $scope.content = {};
    MyPDFService.getPDFReport().then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.content = response;
            $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.content);
        },
        function (errResponse) {
            $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
        });
});

_myPDFServiceFactory.getPDFReport = function(){
var deferred = $q.defer();
var repUrl = appURL+'/myReports'+'/getPDFReport.form';
$http.get(repUrl,{responseType:'blob'})
.then(
function (response) {
deferred.resolve(response.data);
},
function(errResponse){
console.error('Error'+errResponse);
deferred.reject(errResponse);
}
);
return deferred.promise;
}
```

javacode:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPDFReport", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/octet-stream")
    @ResponseBody public byte[] showPDFReport(final HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:/reports/myDataReport.pdf");
            return org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading file" + e);
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

With above java code,i could able to read the PDF and display in chrome successfully. However its not working in internetExplorer. How to make the above code work in IE.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your question includes (some of) your code, you don't describe what you tried and what exactly the problem is. What happens when you debug the JavaScript? What's the difference between Chrome and IE? We can't do this for you with reasonable effort...

Comment: @sruetti - Trust me i spent days on this to resolve.There are no errors shown in IE console. It says Initializing and doesn't load any pdf, whereas in chrome it immediately opens the PDF.I came across many online links but with no luck

Comment: Well... I assume your Java code gets called and finishes returning the PDF, correct? MyPDFService.getPDFReport().then( function (response) { [..] }); gets called? You may want to consider other tags (e.g. javascript) to attract the right experts...

Comment: Added more tags..java code returns the byte[] of the file(pdf).Hopefully i will get answer here..@sruetti