# unable to display the PDF in IE when PDF is in local drive

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, itext, jsoup

My requirement is very simple but unable to get the solution.I am working with angularjs and java application.
I want to read the PDF document stored in local drive and display on the webpage and should  work in IE and chrome.
I have tried different approaches using PDF.js, Jsoup.jar and iTextAPI.jar,but still could not able to succeed displaying on webpage both in IE and chrome.

Any suggestions would be of great help. I want to know an API which can be used to read the PDF from local drive and show on the webpage(should work on IE and chrome).

I have tried this [read the pdf and display in IE,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808287/read-the-pdf-and-display-in-ie?noredirect=1#comment76599017_44808287) but could not able to show PDF in IE. No errors are shown on the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read the pdf and display in IE,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808287/read-the-pdf-and-display-in-ie)

Comment: @ChrisG - That was raised by me only and have not got any solution. My request is to please see if that has accepted answer before you share the link.I have tried everything but with no luck.....Any suggestions?If you read my question i myself had tagged to that link...

Comment: Doesn't matter why you did it, you aren't allowed to post a question twice.

Comment: hmmm ok but is that ok for you without reading the shared link(even the one which u shared doesn't have any answers not even closer)..I'm here to get some inputs...

Comment: I'm guessing the problem isn't where the file is located but the fact that you're trying to get this to run on IE. It's a shitty browser nobody should use. The only thing I can think of is to find some conversion utility that turns a PDF into HTML.

Comment: I have already tried converting that, but of no luck :(

Comment: So detect the browser, and if it's IE, send the PDF as attachment / download. That way the user can look at it using Adobe Reader or whatever.

Comment: Or remove the PDF from the loop, access the data that the PDF is generated from directly, and display that.

Comment: PDF contains images too..and its a dynamic PDF..i think none of the above solutions work..But i'm surprised this is common usage how come we don't have a proper solution yet..thanks for your inputs@ChrisG

Comment: The proper solution is to NOT USE IE. We have it.

Comment: Do not open duplicate questions.

Comment: You didn't answer the questions in the other question.